# snakemake: conda env relative path to the specific smk file, not the execution path (i.e. Snakefile with rule all)

Tags: conda, bioinformatics, snakemake

I've written a snakemake workflow and to make code more manageable I split the rules into separate `smk` files. My current directory structure looks like this:

```sh
|-- Snakefile # with statements like include: utils/align.smk 
|-- config.yaml
|-- envs
|   `-- vep.yml
`-- utils
    |-- align.smk
    |-- envs
    |   |-- alignment.yml
    |   |-- mutect2.yml
    |   |-- quality_check.yml
    |   `-- vep.yml
    |-- process_reads.smk
    `-- variant_calling.smk
```

I also wrote the workflow to rely on conda and specified all the requirements to separate yaml files. Now, the location of the files is specified in `config.yaml`, for example:

```yaml
CONDA_ALIGNMENT: "utils/envs/alignment.yml"
```

and then rules in `align.smk` call those by `conda: config['CONDA_ALIGNMENT']`.

However, now that I try to run snakemake, I get the following errror:

```sh
snakemake -np --profile cluster --jobs 2 --use-conda --force
Building DAG of jobs...
WorkflowError:
Failed to open source file /path/to/exec/utils/utils/envs/alignment.yml
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/exec/utils/utils/envs/alignment.yml'
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 228, in create
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 98, in hash
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 80, in content
  File "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 67, in _get_content
```

Note that `utils` directory appears twice in the path for the file snakemake cannot find. All the other files in inputs/params/outputs... work when specified relative to the main Snakefile, rather than the particular smk file. I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how to deal with this in more snakemake way.

The fastest fix I can come up with would be to move the smk files out of utils but then it would be quite messy...

Comment: Maybe it would help to show (part of) the Snakefile and how you execute snakemake. But what about using: `CONDA_ALIGNMENT: "envs/alignment.yml"`? (note `utils` dir removed)

Comment: I think it's relative to the snakefile, not the execution path